# Implementing a Coq tactic in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, coq

I want to implement a tactic called `solve`, which can solve a linear equation expressed as a theorem. For example :

```
Theorem leq :  exists x , x + 3 = 2*x - 3 .
Proof.
solve.
Qed.
```

I want to implement "solve" as  a tactic in Coq source code (in OCaml). How can I pass the goal (the linear equation) to OCaml and after solving it, return the value and complete the proof?

Answer (score 4):

See the following [introduction to Coq plugins](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/your-first-coq-plugin/) as a working example of implementing a tactic in OCaml. Note however that what the decision procedure you want to write is non-trivial, and:

- it's not clear to me that you couldn't use `ring` or `omega` that already exists
- proof-by-reflection approaches may allow you to develop the tactic in an easier and safer way, by reflecting the desired equation in a Coq datatype and implementing the solving procedure in Coq directly -- a small part of OCaml code could then be used to automate the syntactic reflection.